# Android - Handling changing apn connection

Tags: android, connection, apn

I was wondering how Android is doing that.

**Example**:

1. WAP Push indicates an incoming MMS.
2. Change APN to MMS.
3. Download MMS.
4. Restore connectivity to default APN.

So how is this change of APN done?

**Why**:
I want to use an other APN to connect to the internet instead of the default or MMS APN.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4a4d8fbc87d20c/a7abeb949cd8b3ba?lnk=gst&q=3g+WiFi+simultaneously#a7abeb949cd8b3ba

Comment: @Jens, the link does not answer the question clearly. Even I'm looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Following Activity solves your problem of changing default APN and than revert back to original.

```
package com.slk.apnapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class NewAPNActivity extends Activity {
/*
 * Information of all APNs Details can be found in
 * com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider
 */
public static final Uri APN_TABLE_URI = Uri
        .parse("content://telephony/carriers");
/*
 * Information of the preferred APN
 */
public static final Uri PREFERRED_APN_URI = Uri
        .parse("content://telephony/carriers/preferapn");
private static final String TAG = "CHANGE_APN";
public static final String NEW_APN = "NewAPN";

private int getDafaultAPN() {
    Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(PREFERRED_APN_URI,
            new String[] { "_id", "name" }, null, null, null);
    int id = -1;
    if (c != null) {
        try {
            if (c.moveToFirst())
                id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        c.close();
    }
    return id;

}

/*
 * Set an apn to be the default apn for web traffic Require an input of the
 * apn id to be set
 */
public boolean setDefaultAPN(int id) {
    boolean res = false;
    ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    // See /etc/apns-conf.xml. The TelephonyProvider uses this file to
    // provide
    // content://telephony/carriers/preferapn URI mapping
    values.put("apn_id", id);
    try {
        resolver.update(PREFERRED_APN_URI, values, null, null);
        Cursor c = resolver.query(PREFERRED_APN_URI, new String[] { "name",
                "apn" }, "_id=" + id, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            res = true;
            c.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return res;
}

private int checkNewAPN() {
    int id = -1;
    Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(APN_TABLE_URI,
            new String[] { "_id", "name" }, "name=?",
            new String[] { NEW_APN }, null);
    if (c == null) {
        id = -1;
    } else {
        int record_cnt = c.getCount();
        if (record_cnt == 0) {
            id = -1;
        } else if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")).equalsIgnoreCase(
                    NEW_APN)) {
                id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            }
        }
        c.close();
    }
    return id;
}

public int addNewAPN() {
    int id = -1;
    ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", NEW_APN);
    values.put("apn", NEW_APN);

    /*
     * The following three field values are for testing in Android emulator
     * only The APN setting page UI will ONLY display APNs whose 'numeric'
     * filed is TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_SIM_OPERATOR_NUMERIC. On
     * Android emulator, this value is 310260, where 310 is mcc, and 260
     * mnc. With these field values, the newly added apn will appear in
     * system UI.
     */
    values.put("mcc", "310");
    values.put("mnc", "260");
    values.put("numeric", "310260");

    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        Uri newRow = resolver.insert(APN_TABLE_URI, values);
        if (newRow != null) {
            c = resolver.query(newRow, null, null, null, null);

            // Obtain the apn id
            int idindex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
            c.moveToFirst();
            id = c.getShort(idindex);
            Log.d(TAG, "New ID: " + id + ": Inserting new APN succeeded!");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    if (c != null)
        c.close();
    return id;
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    int id = checkNewAPN();
    int default_id = getDafaultAPN();

    if (id == -1) {
        id = addNewAPN();
    }

    if (setDefaultAPN(id)) {
        Log.i(TAG, NEW_APN
                + " set new default APN successfully and Default id is "
                + id);
    }
    if (setDefaultAPN(default_id)) {
        Log.i(TAG,
                NEW_APN
                        + " set previous default APN successfully and Default id is "
                        + default_id);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raj, Your code solve my problem and bounty will be awarded to you.

Comment: @HiteshPatel : You can also check :[this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zhengpei/archive/2009/10/13/managing-apn-data-in-google-android.aspx) for better example. :)

Comment: Ok. but it creates a new point of APN and set it to default.

I just need to change to the corporate APN, which is already configured and available, but it is not the default (and this is expected to remain).

The change occurs at the start of a corporate application, and after turning off the application phone goes back to the default APN.

Comment: @Al_Tazir, Obviously, you can do that by finding the existing corporate APN by name and store it's id as future reference, and After that you can change default to new APN, when you complete your work with new APN setting just set stored corporate APN's id as default APN.

Comment: @HiteshPatel Followed your steps but no dialog box pops up to give permission.